# USB_Cam, Could not open MJPEG Decoder

Tags: usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever I run usb_cam with pixel_format:="mjpeg", I get the following error:

usb_cam video_device set to [/dev/video1]
...
usb_cam pixel_format set to [mjpeg]
[mjpeg @ 0x7fabe40f0160]codec type or id mismatches
Could not open MJPEG Decoder
Segmentation Fault

I'm using a Logitech Webcam Pro 9000, on Ubuntu 11.04, with the latest "usb_cam" downloaded from the bosch-ros-pkg repository. usb_cam works great when I set pixel_format to "yuyv", and I can see the image with image_view. However, the frame rates for "mjpeg" should be 4x higher than "yuyv" at this camera's native resolution (according to the list at http://www.quickcamteam.net/devices/logitech_uvc_frame_format_list.pdf). I would ultimately like to use this webcam to track a 'fast' moving target, one that I should be able to catch at 30fps, but not reliably catch 5-7.5 fps.

I've installed ffmpeg and libavcodec-dev from Ubuntu's software center. I'd be happy to supply any additional information, but I'm not sure what to look for.

- Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10544/usb_cam,-could-not-open-mjpeg-decoder/) by [davidcw](https://answers.ros.org/users/811/davidcw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-07-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cvcook](https://answers.ros.org/users/23122/cvcook/) on 2015-07-09**:
The link below: https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1281 seems broken. Does anyone has an answer to this? Same problem here. I am using Indigo, usb_cam and Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed up CvCaptureCAM_DShow to allow MJPG and setting of all the webcam parameters.
Fixes are against 2.3.0 see https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1281

---

Originally posted by [mgb](https://answers.ros.org/users/1022/mgb/) with karma: 16 on 2011-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0